# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM MessagesRead 
WHERE [To] <> 'Feadmin'
  AND [To] <> 'Catalonia'
  AND [To] <> 'Bromordia'
  AND [From] <> 'Feadmin'
  AND [From] <> 'Catalonia'
  AND [From] <> 'Bromordia'
  AND MessageID IN (SELECT MessageID 
                    FROM Messages 
                    WHERE TickNr < ((SELECT TickNumber FROM CurrentTick)-1000))
  AND Saved = 0 AND [Read] =1;

DELETE FROM Messages 
WHERE MessageID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MessageID FROM MessagesRead);

DELETE FROM MessagesAdmin 
WHERE MessageID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MessageID FROM Messages);

DELETE from DiscussionMessages 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Inserted,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 6000

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I've just upgraded from SQL Server 2012 to 2014. I'm running the above stored procedure which has worked until now getting the error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Engine_DeleteMessages, Line 9
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have obviously worked out it shouldn't say `WHERE TickNr <` but I can't think of a better way to word this, or why it was working until I upgraded?

Comment: It looks like your old data did not have the duplicate.  The IN statement gives you a chance for a number of records returned, as does most of the statement.  Maybe add a Distinct to the MessageID IN (SELECT ...)?

Answer (score 3):

Thats a pretty good error message, pretty explanatory. So you need the subquery to return a single value/row, by using a where clause or `TOP`.

Either:

```
SELECT TickNumber FROM CurrentTick WHERE id = <someID>;
```

OR:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TickNumber FROM CurrentTick [ORDER BY some_col]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple rows in CurrentTick? If there was once only one row in that table, then the above query would have worked. Could it be that there are now 2 or more rows in that table?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one row... Thank you, apologies I never even thought to check that table, it seems that when I've restored the database from back up, it's duplicated a couple of tables. I've removed the duplicate in this table and it's all working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that `TickNr` is lower than any possible `TickNumber` in `CurrentTick` this might be a good case for the `ALL` operator:

```
AND MessageID IN (SELECT MessageID 
                    FROM Messages 
                    WHERE TickNr < ALL((SELECT TickNumber FROM CurrentTick)-1000))
```

This would test the `TickNr` against all values returned in the subquery.

If there can/should only be one row returned you could use `top 1` in the subquery to ensure that the subquery returns a single value.